# Google chrome dev tools don't work as per my input value

Tags: css, responsive-design, google-chrome-devtools

This is the question about Google chrome dev tools and CSS. As following codes, though I input "@media (max-width:1000px)" on style sheet of VSCODE, the tools change to Responsive Web Design at 750px(75%). I don't zoom, and write "viewport" on html. Also the scale is 1.0. Please tell me the solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
div {
    width: max(400px, 50%);
    height: 400px;
    background-color: coral;
}
@media (max-width: 1000px){
    div {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you are changing the viewport properly and not the zoom? https://imgur.com/p4lprvq

Comment: Thank you for a comment. After I get that, I confirmed my settings again. Then, I found  out the cause. The cause was the zoom of page. I just paid attention to the zoom of my touchpad. Sorry for such a basic question. In Japanese, but I share the link I could solve the cause.
https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/2003/11/news019.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of my comment, the cause was the zoom of page. By  putting back the zoom, I could solve the question.